# The date overflows the reputation graph's tooltip bounds

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, tooltips, reputation-graph

In the reputation subtab on the Activity page, in the [graph view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/513150/justin?tab=reputation), there's a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug):

[image: Image of the tooltip for the reputation graph, with the year exceeding the tooltip box's bounds]

The year (e.g., 2022) does not fit in the tooltip (shown when you hover over a bar on the graph).

I'm using Chrome, version 99.0.4844.82, on Windows 11.

Comment: Which browser and which browser version do you use? Which OS? I just tried Firefox and Chrome on Ubuntu (latest versions, both at 100% zoom) with your graph and I can't reproduce the issue, the date is shown in a smaller font size to fit the box.

Comment: @Marijn: I use Chrome, version 99[.0.4844.82], on Windows 11.

Comment: I concur with @Marijn. The only thing wrong with the box is really big top padding, and no bottom padding for me.

Comment: @Luuklag: Could you share an image? Do you also use Ubuntu? I would really like to know from a Windows user, to see whether the problem is for everyone using Windows or just me.

Comment: @Justin using FireFox and Chrome on Mac OS Monterry. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzZvF.png)

Comment: @Luuklag: Thanks. So I guess it's a Windows-only issue...

Comment: @Justin, no in fact its a Justin only issue. I just fired up a windows machine, and it looks exactly the same here as in the image I shared before, at least on firefox. I don't have a chrome running on this machine, and corporate policy won't allow me to install it.